# get value of checked radio button using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, css-selectors

I have the following form:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="group-stack" value="grouped" checked>grouped<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group-stack" value="stacked">stacked
</form>
```

I want to get the currently selected radio button's value using d3.

The following attempts have been unsuccessful:

```
var val = d3.select('input[name="group-stack"]').checked; //undefined
var val = d3.select('input[name="group-stack"][checked]')[0][0].value //always 'grouped' regardless of which radio is selected
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
d3.select('input[name="group-stack"]:checked').node().value
```

Comment: I like .node() better than [0][0]. I'm glad you answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I'm a little late to the party but, FWIW, this is the pure d3 way:

```
d3.select('input[name="group-stack"]:checked').property("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

ah... got it

```
d3.select('input[name="group-stack"]:checked')[0][0].value
```